# C# launch user control as an exe

Tags: c#, wpf, exe

I have a C# application that has multiple tabs on the main form. They are currently all within one executable. Each tab currently contains a User Control. For performance reasons, I want to load each user control as a separate exe so that they have their own process space. Is that possible? Do we have a quick sample for it (a link etc)?

If not possible, are there other alternatives for this scenario?

Comment: Why an executable file? User Controls are stored in dll-files if you want it to solve like this.

Comment: Is this WPF or Winforms?

Comment: Sounds like you just want to implement threading...

Comment: As mentioned above look into running threads in each user control.

Comment: @NWard Processes and Threading are very different, the separate process guarantees isolation between the separate user controls so that they may not crash one another. But you are right that that may not be what the asker is after.

Comment: I'm aware, but as the OP specified performance as his motivation, it seems like threading is what they are actually interested in

Comment: Threading is definitely a solution. But a process would give it's own UI thread and memory (have a lot of data per tab/user control) and will not kill the entire application if one of them fails. If have independent processes is not worth the effort, I can go with threads. This is WPF.

Comment: @Padmaja you should load all your data in a background thread, while keeping the UI thread free to do UI-related stuff. It would also be helpful if you could add more information about what areas of your application are performing bad. Such as what kind of controls, if there are large Lists, are you making sure UI Virtualization is being honored, and the like.

Comment: There is a lot of data in the application (per user control) and the system gets Out of Memory exceptions some times. I can make the tabs to load parallel using threads, but was hoping that a process for each would resolve all the issues. I am not sure about the UI or Data virtualization but am using third-party grids (infragistics) to display the data.

Answer (score 0):

If the user control number is fixed you could just create a single library project, which contains them all, and then one project (with an .exe target) for each control.

Or you could do it at runtime, by compiling a little piece of code that will actually create a form and run it with the control inside.

But the question is: why do you want to do this? as NWard suggested in the comments, you may just want to use threading or tasks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WPF, take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909794%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at how MAF may be used with WPF add-ins. This allows your WPF controls to be loaded into a separate process space.